# Detecting failed fingerprint authentication attempts in an Android app

Tags: authentication, android, fingerprint

Disclaimer: First of all I'm not an Android developer but a security professional.

My company wants to implement fingerprint authentication in its Android app and I'm wondering if there is any way to log the failed authentication attempts in the application?

According to my current understanding after the application calls the fingerprint authentication API of the OS it does not see how many times the user failed to provide a valid fingerprint, it only waits for a callback containing the key extracted from the keystore in case of successful authentication or a "fingerprint authentication canceled" message if the user decides not to use the fingerprint authentication and fall back to PIN authentication instead (let's suppose that this is implemented).

Comment: Hi Richard, and welcome to security.stackexchance.com.  Your question is more about how to use a specific API, rather than information security.  I think you might have more luck getting your question answered on StackOverflow.  I've put in a request to have it migrated there to hopefully get you some better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way to log failed authentication attempts inside your application. You can use the [`authenticate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html#authenticate(android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.CryptoObject,%20android.os.CancellationSignal,%20int,%20android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) method from the `FingerprintManager` class. Then, using an instance of the [`AuthenticationCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback.html) you can log to any analytics platform (Firebase, for example) the events for each one of the callbacks. Or you can just log them on your own servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are three other callbacks aside from `onAuthenticationSucceeded`:

- `onAuthenticationError`
  For fatal errors such as timeouts/lockouts.
- `onAuthenticationFailed`
  For non-fatal errors where a fingerprint was aquired but not recognized.
- `onAuthenticationHelp`
  For non-fatal errors where a fingerprint couldn't be aquired, e.g. the sensor is dirty or the user didn't keep the finger steady.