# Android, not possible to catch biometric fingerprint unlock events?

Tags: android, fingerprint, biometrics

Is there any way to receive callback when fingerprint unlocking failed on Android lock screen? I couldnt find any broadcast intent or receiver for this. It's possible to catch failed unlocks for pins, patterns etc. via onPasswordFailed on DeviceAdminReceiver but its not applying to fingerprint unlocking.

Cheers

Comment: Did you not find: [Detecting failed fingerprint authentication attempts in an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46776686/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang, that case is different. Its about catching fingerprint events where you implement fingerprint auth on your own. Whereas in my case, its already implemented by android or manufacturer on lock screen.

Comment: Ah, not aware of any callback for lock screen. My guess is such feedback may lead to some type of a brute force attack. It may help to read: https://source.android.com/security/biometric

Comment: If an app have device admin privilege, it can catch device unlock failed events for pin, password and pattern. Android have specific intent callbacks/events for those but looks like there is no such thing for unlocking device with finger print, probably not for face unlocking either. I think they can implement one in the future, why not. Dont think there is a security concern as it's just a callback informing unlock failed.

Comment: Seems like there is no receiver intent actions for biometrics. If it was in the future, it would probably be implemented in DeviceAdminReceiver class like other lock/unlock callbacks. At this point without a global intent action receiver, I might need to dig into android.hardware.biometric which is system provided implementation of biometrics in api >28 , not androidx.biometric which is application wide. System wide version looks a bit more complex. I'll check this out and update here.